# Pseudo Streaming an MP4 file

Tags: html, html5-video, mp4, jwplayer, pseudo-streaming

I have a few questions regarding pseudo streaming an MP4 file.

1. Is the entire file downloaded, eg. if I scrub 1 minute in to a 2 minute video, will only the second half be downloaded thus saving bandwidth?
2. Is there anyway I can check this using Chrome dev tools?
3. How would I go about creating a MP4 that's ready for pseudo streaming? I've read the meta data needs to be at the start of the file, how can I do this? Is there any recommended software?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) The entire file is not downloaded.

2) You will be able to check when the file is requested via the Network panel to see if the start requests are being set.

3) Just make sure to encode using HandBrake, use the default settings and web optimized. - http://handbrake.fr/, alternatively, if you have an MP4 already and just need to move the meta data, this tool can be used - http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/

Finally, you need to make sure that you actually install the mp4 pseudo streaming module for your web server, and in your JW Player embed code, set a startparam value, which is either start, startime, or apstart, depending on your web server configuration. We have a guide about this here - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1430518-pseudo-streaming-in-flash

Keep in mind, if you are using html5 , the pseudo streaming module is not needed, as html5  already does this, and the pseudo streaming module is really only for Flash.

Comment: Another excellent tool that does nothing but place the moovatom in an existing MP4 where it belongs, and can process batches of files, is called "MP4 FastStart:" http://www.datagoround.com/lab/

Comment: So does handbrake move the meta data automatically?

Comment: Yeah, as long as you enable web optimized while encoding.